# Exclude few document sections from the ToC in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, bookmarks

I would like to exclude certain sections from the ToC.

I already tried this by manipulating the tocdeph-counter. However, it is not working, and I do not understand why.

My code does not produce a ToC visible in the document itself. I am referring to the ToC shown by PDF readers for file navigation (here Acrobat reader):

[image]

Do you have an idea for me?

Please see the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{red}
\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Doe} 

\begin{document}

% Start with a letter which shall be in the ToC as Letter
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Letter}
Here a letter will be inserted
\clearpage

% Now the CV starts and shall be in the TOC only with a single entry named CV 
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CV}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}} % Is not working as the following two sections appear in the ToC!

\section{Something which shall not be in the ToC}
\section{Something which shall not be in the ToC 2}

% From now on an Appendix starts and the sections shall be included in ToC again
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\section{I shall be visible in the ToC of the PDF}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not produce any ToC.

Comment: Thx, added details for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You can change the value of `bookmarksdepth` to -1 to suppress the bookmark of the next entry (s) until you issue `\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=1}`

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{red}
\firstname{John} 
\familyname{Doe} 

\begin{document}
    
    % Start with a letter which shall be in the ToC as Letter
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Letter}
    Here a letter will be inserted
    \clearpage
    
    % Now the CV starts and shall be in the TOC only with a single entry named CV 
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{CV}
            
    \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-1}% supress bookmark <<<<<<<<<<
    \section{Something which shall not be in the ToC}
    \section{Something which shall not be in the ToC 2}
    
    \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=1} %again <<<<<<<<<<
    % From now on an Appendix starts and the sections shall be included in ToC again
    \section{I shall be visible in the ToC of the PDF}
    
\end{document
```